# Importance of $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$ in the proof that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

I'm working on a proof to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is a field. I have completed the proof, however the question has the following hint "*You should use the fact that $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$*." Now I'm not sure that I've really utilized this fact in my proof at all. I'm going to outline my proof below and hopefully someone might be able to tell me exactly where this fact comes into play.

The only place I can really think of is to say that since $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$ then that implies that $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ but $\mathbb{Q} \neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ which implies the containment $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) \subset \mathbb{R}$ but I don't see how that's necessary to complete the proof. I emailed my professor and he mentioned that one of the properties I need to verify will definitely require the hint, that it will be subtle but to pay attention to the expressions I end up with.

---

**The proof**

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2) = \{a + b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field comprised of all rational ($a,b$) and irrational ($\sqrt2$) numbers and their sums and products ($a + b\sqrt2$). I claim that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, and hence a field itself.

The additive identity from $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

- $0 = 0 + 0\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

The multiplicative identity from $\mathbb{R}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

- $1 = 1 + 0\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Now, let $x = a+b\sqrt2$ and $y = c+d\sqrt2$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is closed under addition:

- $x + y = (a+b\sqrt2) + (c+d\sqrt2) = (a+c) + (b\sqrt2 + d\sqrt2) = (a+c) + (b+d)\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is closed under multiplication:

- $xy = (a+b\sqrt2)(c+d\sqrt2) = ac + ad\sqrt2 + bc\sqrt2 + 2bd = (ac + 2bd) + (ad + bc)\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Since addition and multiplication are commutative and associative in $\mathbb{R}$ that means they are commutative and associative in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. Similarly since multiplication distributes over addition in $\mathbb{R}$ that means the distributive property holds in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ as well.

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is closed under additive inverses:

- $-x = -(a+b\sqrt2) = -a-b\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Finally, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is closed under multiplicative inverses:

- $x^{-1} = \frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2} = \frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2}\frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a-b\sqrt2} = \frac{a-b\sqrt2}{(a+b\sqrt2)(a-b\sqrt2)} = \frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a^2 - 2b^2} = \frac{a}{a^2 - 2b^2} - \frac{b}{a^2 - 2b^2}\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$   $\square$

---

Again, I believe my proof is acceptable, I'm just worried that because I don't feel like I'm utilizing the hint properly then I'm going to get some points off. If anyone can help me see where the fact that $\sqrt2 \notin \mathbb{Q}$ fits in to any of the above verifications then I would really appreciate that.

Comment: $a^2-2b^2$ might be zero even if $(a,b)\neq(0,0).$

Comment: If $a+b\sqrt2 \neq 0$, how do you know that $a-b\sqrt2 \neq 0$? (So that, $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt2} \frac{a-b\sqrt2}{a-b\sqrt2}$ makes sense.)

Comment: Replace $\sqrt{2}$ with $\sqrt{4}$ and trace through your solution, and you will get the problems above ^

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, azif00 and GarethMa great hints guys, exactly the guidance I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: The structure $\mathbb{Q} (a) $ is a field even if $a\in\mathbb {Q} $. Perhaps your text is using  non standard definition of $\mathbb{Q} (a) $.

Comment: You are implicitly using that $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ every time you assume the expression $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is unique, that is, that $a+b\sqrt{2}=r+s\sqrt{2}$ if and only if $a=r$ and $b=s$. In particular, in asserting $a+b\sqrt{2}\neq 0$ means $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the definition of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2):= \{ a+b\sqrt 2 : a,b\in \mathbf Q  \}$, must be $a,b\in \mathbf Q$.

So $a \neq \pm \sqrt2 b$ **always**, because $a$ must be rational! **and $\sqrt 2 \notin \mathbf Q$**.

Therefore, $a^2-2b^2\neq 0$ **always**!, and then you can do that procedure for the multiplicative inverses.

That procedure only makes sense because $a^2-2b^2\neq 0$, and this is granted by the  fact that $a \neq \pm \sqrt2 b$ always dued to $a\in \mathbf Q$ **and** $\sqrt 2 \notin \mathbf Q$.

Comment: Excellent! That makes perfect sense. I had a feeling it had something to do with the existence of the multiplicative inverse but couldn't see it for myself. Thank you for your contribution Satyat